# Android debug.keystore issue

Tags: android

i've got a little problem while generating my SHA1 for an app i'm developing, (please understand i'm really new to android developement).
I'm using ECLIPSE on win 7, and the .android/debug.keystore file seems to be correctly generated... the point is: when i navigate inside c:\Users\myUser.android via windows console i try to run the file this way:

```
c:\Users\myUser\.android>debug.keystore
```

When i press submit,it open the "impossible open the file" window, and it asks me to select a program, local or on internet, to be able to run the file..

I know it's quite simple operation, but i'm gettin mad on it... What am i doing wrong?

Thank you all

Comment: u will need to use JDK keytool for generating SHA1 or MD5 keys instead of trying to run debug.keystore

Comment: Run `notepad` and click to open a file, navigate to `c:\Users\myUser\.android` and open the `debug.keystore` file. Or try running with: `c:\Users\myUser\.android>notepad debug.keystore`

Comment: @daniloisr tryng to open it this way just doesn't work... it just show me a bunch of garbage, but thank you

Comment: @prosper forgive me but where can i find/navigate into the JDK? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you cannot open debug.keystore, to get your hash use the `keytool` like is described here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey?hl=pt-BR#getdebugfingerprint

Comment: @daniloisr i've read that docs but unfortunately this is the linux command, and i can't figure out what i shoul type into my windows shell to make it run...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved! The answer of prosper was actually the right one, i should execute the keytool command inside the JDK folder that contains the keytool... Many thanks to everyone

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

More precisely it would be like this

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\your_account_name.android\debug.keystore | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64

You will have to download OpeSSL and extract in a folder, mine is C:\OperSSL
Execute this code inside the JDK bin folder